# To simplify a harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that the following is correct. How do we get the LHS from the RHS?
$$\sum_{k=j+1}^n\frac1{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\frac1k$$

Comment: **1)** It doesn't work if $j=0$ for example, so please make sure to write down the problem in full. **2)** What have *you* tried, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first sum is
$$S_1=\frac1j+\frac1{j+1}+\cdots+\frac1{n-1}.$$
Your second sum is
$$S_2=\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{n-1}.$$
Your third sum is
$$S_3=\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{j-1}.$$
It should be clear that $S_1=S_2-S_3$, but $S_3$ consists of the
first $j-1$ terms in the sum $S_2$; removing them leaves the last $n-j$
terms, which form the sum $S_1$.

Comment: Nice.  TY Lord Shark of the Unknown.